# C# compiler strange attempt to cast short result to integer

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, modulo

I'm trying to execute a modulo operation with 2 numbers of type `short` :

```
short short1 = 1; // or any other short value
short short2 = 2;
short result = short1 % short2;
```

But I get this compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why does the compiler think the result should be of type `int`?
The result must be between 0 and min(short1, short2) and both those values are `short`.

Comment: Take a look at the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#remainder-operator) for the remainder operator - you'll see there is no definition of % for shorts, only ints. Becauase a short can fit inside an int, both your short1 and short2 are automatically upgraded to ints and the calculation is carried out using ints. This means your result is an int, which cannot then be back-assigned to a short without a cast because of the potential loss of information (int is larger than short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `short` numbers are lifted to `int` **before** applying the module operator, since the remainder operator is not defined for types smaller than `int`.

So you have `int int.operator %(int left, int right)`and the return type is `int`.

You can explicitly cast to `short` since you know that the result is representable by a `short`.

```
short result = (short)(short1 % short2);
```